# Text widget shows text with strange styles (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-hooks

I'm using Provider in Flutter for state management. And I want to display some text in my widget using this Provider. The test is shown but is looks very strange height or padding I don't know. So here is a code.

```
class JobDetailsScreen extends HookWidget {
  const JobDetailsScreen({required this.id, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final String id;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final job = Provider.of<JobsNotifier>(context).currentJob;
    var loading = Provider.of<JobsNotifier>(context).isLoadingCurrentJob;
    useEffect(() {
      if (job == null) {
        Future.microtask(() async {
          await Provider.of<JobsNotifier>(context, listen: false)
              .getCurrentJob(id);
        });
      }
      return () => {};
    }, [id]);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const NavBarTop(
        title: 'Job Details',
        innerAppBar: true,
      ),
      body: loading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(job.title,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24)),
                    Text(job.company,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18)),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        try {
                          await openUrl(job.applyUrl!);
                        } on String catch (e) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text(
                              e,
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ));
                        }
                      },
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                              const Size(double.infinity, 50))),
                      child: const Text('Apply'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I see this on my screen

[Screen with wrong text behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcKLq.png)

I'm expecting widget to show text the right way without any paading and some redundant height.
It should be like this:

[Right text behaviour screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECGX8.png)

Comment: Similar code works fine for me. Maybe it's because of the parent of this Widget. I just used MaterialApp. What are you using?

Comment: @ivo yes, Material App as well. But as I said below the it seems to me that the issue is in dynamic values which is used in Text widget -> Text(job.title, styles...)

Comment: Maybe the response has newlines? Like maybe job.title equals "\nUI/UI Design Lead\n\n". Try use `job.title.trim()` maybe

Comment: @ivo thanks a lot, man, I completely forgot that I received 'dirty' data because this data is parsed from different websites. Thank you again)

Comment: @Ivo if it's not difficult for you, could you suggest what you wrote as answer? And I would select it as right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response might contain newlines. Like maybe job.title equals `"\nUI/UI Design Lead\n\n"`.

Try use `job.title.trim()` so any leading and trailing whitespaces and newlines are removed.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to run your code, and it seems to work fine without any padding to the text widgets or height, heres's a screenshot:

i believe what you can do is to check through you NavBarTop widget, to see if there could be any property affecting this.

[image: Code test]

Comment: As I understood the issue is in dynamic value 'job' which is received from Provider, because in case when I use text value directly or even from variables is looks fine. But once this data is let's say dynamic in runtime, it looks awfull.